# Wicket authorization: Grant access based on page model

Tags: spring, hibernate, security, spring-security, wicket

I'm developing a fairly standard web application with Wicket, Spring & Hibernate. I've been using `wicket-auth-roles` and `spring-security` to authenticate users, and now want to add more fine grained authorizations to my applications.

In my applications users are members of groups, and groups have access to a subset of Hibernate objects that I use as wicket `IModel` objects. As such the decision whether or not a user may view certain page does not depend on the page path, but on the page ***model***. (Most implementations of authorization for Wicket I've seen either grant access to a url or restrict it; they do not perform any checks on the model object.)

At present I've implemented this restriction as a custom [IAuthorizationStrategy](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/authorization/IAuthorizationStrategy.html) like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isActionAuthorized(final Component component, final Action action) {
    if (!(component instanceof GenePage))
        // We only check access to the GenePage for now
        return true;

    // Figure out from component what Gene the user is trying to view
    Gene gene = (Gene) component.getDefaultModelObject();
    User user = MySession.get().getUserModel().getObject();
    return geneDAO.hasAccess(user, gene);
}
```

The problem with this implementation is that it fully composes the page and only in `Page#onConfigure` throws an uncaught `UnauthorizedActionException`. So far I've been unable to catch this exception, so it's logged as a problem even though it's part of the normal program flow. Fully composing the page also triggers a few actions in my page constructor and `Page#onInitialize` that I would only like to run if the user may actually view the Page.

**Can anyone recommend me a better approach to restrict page access based on whether users have access to the Model object?**

Solutions that tie in anywhere along the stack using Hibernate, Spring, Spring Security, Wicket and/or Wicket-Auth-Roles would be preferred. I know there are other wicket auth-integrations out there, so if you feel those could help in this instance, please let me know!

Comment: Just now reading up on [Spring Domain Object Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/domain-acls.html); Thought it might be a useful link to include for others while I work on a possible implementation.

Comment: I think you should put your access code in `isInstantiationAuthorized` method isntead, that it's called before the component is created.

Comment: @polypiel I'd thought about doing that, but within `isInstantiationAuthorized` I only have access to the `componentClass`, not the Model object. How do you suggest I access the model object from within that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that you expect a weird behaviour. This authz mechanism is designed to protect against *Insecure Direct Object Reference Vulnerabilities*. So you should not use it as a "part of the normal program flow". If you have kind of valid use cases then such kind of "hasAccess" failures should be handled somehow differently as valid behaviour, you should use some other mechanism, probably something custom built, as in most cases it will be very specific to your application.